# Getting difference calling the function names inside an objects in JavaScript(NodeJs)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose I have an 2 objects `x` and `y`. The details are written in the code below.

```js
let x = {
  publish: function() {
    console.log(this.publish.name);
  }
};
let y = {};
y.publish = function() {
  console.log(this.publish.name);
};
x.publish();
y.publish();
```

I was getting difference in the outputs calling `x.publish()` and `y.publish()`.
The former returned the name of the function while the latter returned empty. Can anyone explain why is this happening, and is there any other 
possible way I can retrieve the function name in latter(WITHOUT HARDCODING). I am using NodeJs version 8.

Comment: Because the second one is anonymous function hence it has empty string in name property.

Comment: @ManishJangir - I don't think that explains it. Both functions here are technically "anonymous", because they're defined with an anonymous function expression: `function() {...}` - when you could instead have used `function my_func() {...}` Having just looked at the MDN page for the function `name` property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name - it seems that for object properties the `name` does refer to the property name. But this doesn't explain why it doesn't work for `y`. (And why it is an empty string rather than `"anonymous"`.)

Answer (score 0):

Since the function in the second case doesn't have any name associated with it so you get empty string.

```js
let x = {
  publish: function() {
    console.log(this.publish.name);
  }
};
let y = {};
y.publish = function() {
  console.log(this.publish.name);
};

let z = {};
z.publish = function hello() {
  console.log(this.publish.name);
};
x.publish();
y.publish();
z.publish();
```

Comment: Can you explain more as I can't find the name in the first case as well.

Comment: Well when you use the key value pair the funtion name is same as key.

Answer (score 0):

In your second case `y.publish`, you're assigning a variable identifier to the function but not giving it a name. that would be `y.publish = function publish()`

Comment: I think that's what the OP referred to by "*WITHOUT HARDCODING*".

Comment: The function doesn't have a name

Comment: What else is `function publish()`?

Comment: a name, he wrote y.publish = function(){}, that doesn't assign a function a name, it gives it a code identifier. Those are 2 separate things

Answer (score 0):

Basically any time an anonymous function expression appears on the right-hand side of something like an assignment or initialization, like:

```
var boo = function() { /*...*/ };
(or it could be let or const rather than var), or

var obj = {
    boo: function() { /*...*/ }
};
```

or

```
doSomething({
    boo: function() { /*...*/ }
});
```

(those last two are really the same thing), the resulting function will have a name (boo, in the examples).

There's an important, and intentional, exception: Assigning to a property on an existing object:

```
obj.boo = function() { /*...*/ }; // <== Does not get a name
```

Search for **SetFunctionName** on the following:

[1. Property initializer semantics](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object-initializer-runtime-semantics-propertydefinitionevaluation)

[2. Assignment Operator Semantics](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation)

Comment: Is this behaviour documented anywhere? I can't find it on MDN.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks, although I'm not able at the moment to wade through the formal specification to find this. But I did look at the question mentioned that this one is apparently a duplicate of, and that gives some interesting context.